# Compiling and linking with 3rd party libraries

Tags: c, linux, svn

I have a device with ARM processor running linux OS. On my Ubuntu, which is the host with the workspace, I have two folders - the source and the target's filesystem. In order to compile, I have to link to other libraries such as sqlite and openssl, etc. These libraries sources are in the source folder.

After the compilation of the libraries (sqlite, tslib, openssl, etc.), the libraries outputs are installed to the filesystem, so that the ARM linux can run the processes, of course.

The thing is, that in order to compile my processes source code, I have to link them against these libraries. So, My question is, what is the right approach:

1. To compile and install the libraries to the filesystem, and then compile the processes against the libraries that on the filesystem.
2. To compile and install the libraries, but then compile the processes against the libraries that are placed in the source folder.

Maybe it looks the same, but add the fact that we are a team that work on the whole project, so the source code (including the libraries source) and the filesystem are being handled with SVN so all the team can sync and update the code. With the first approach, in case one developer deleted the filesystem, the project won't compile till he has the filesystem and the libraries on it. In the second approach, when a a library such as tslib is updated to the last version, then everyone has to compile the library by themselves cause the output of these libraries are not copied to the filesystem which is sync with the SVN.

In short, Is it better to work with the source and the target are linked in some way (case 1), or does the total separation between the source and the filesystem is smarter approach (case 2).
I tried to be clear as possible and explain the issue, hope I managed doing it.

Comment: For example You have openssl library in source code. Now what you want to do ? I means which process you want compile against the library? Can you provide me any example

Comment: I manage to compile against the openssl library. My question is regarding the location of the library. Should I link my source with the libraries that are in my source or against the libraries that are in the target filesystem.

Comment: As I understood Second approach is best

Comment: Because compiling and installing library to filesystem increase the size of file system